# Silhouette scores for different distance metrics

Tags: clustering, distance-functions

I clustered a data set using PAM with a euclidean distance metric and a pearson correlation distance metric. The average silhouette value of the correlation clusters is higher at most points than the euclidean one, but their maximas are at the same number of clusters, and peaks occur at similar cluster numbers.

Is there any way to compare the two on the same scale?

Comment: It would help if you could post some sample data, &/or sample code. Also, could you post the silhouette figures? (Nb, if SE won't let you, post them to imgur.com & put a link here, then someone can add them for you.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Silhouette scores with different metrics can be made comparable.

Some metrics have range $[0;\infty]$. Others only $[0;1]$ - most likely, the resulting silhouette values will be different.

Even Euclidean and squared Euclidean - which agree on what is "most similar" - will yield a different silhouette.